# Bootstrap columns issue with forms

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap forms and columns together:

Heres my code: https://jsfiddle.net/8r91hep9/

My html looks like:

```
<div class='col-md-6'>
  <input class='input-lg form-control' type='text'>
</div>
<div class='col-md-5'>
  <input class='input-lg form-control' type='text'>
</div>
<div class='col-md-1'>
  <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'>Test</a
</div>
```

I'm trying to get it so for 6 columns, it has the first .form-control, then for five columns, it has the next .form-control, and then for one column it has the button. So all are in a row.

Comment: so what is the problem and close this tag `Test</a`

Comment: It doesn't display like it should? It should be like the default bootstrap columns

Comment: Can someone tell me how I can make this question *more* clear? Literally, I'm trying to put form elements into a grid, using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your link and increase the width of the output section. You will see your code is working correctly and everything will be in a row.